# How to compare two consecutive rows with a reference value in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame of vehicle trajectories. Here's a snapshot:

```
> head(df)
  vehicle frame globalx class velocity lane
1       2    43 6451214     2    37.76    2
2       2    44 6451217     2    37.90    2
3       2    45 6451220     2    38.05    2
4       2    46 6451223     2    38.18    2
5       2    47 6451225     2    38.32    2
6       2    48 6451228     2    38.44    2
```

where, vehicle= vehicle id (repeats because same vehicle is observed in several time frames), frame= frame id of time frames in which it was observed, globalx = x coordinate of the front center of the vehicle, class=type of vehicle (1=motorcycle, 2=car, 3=truck), velocity=speed of vehicles in feet per second, lane= lane number (there are 6 lanes). I think following illustration will better explain the problem:
[image]
The 'frame' represents one tenth of a second i.e. one frame is 0.1 seconds long. At frame 't' the vehicle has globalx coordinate x(t) and at frame 't-1' (0.1 seconds before) it was x(t-1). The reference location is 'U'(globalx=6451179.1116) and I simply want a new column in df called 'u' which has 'yes' in the row where globalx of the vehicle was greater than reference coordinate at 'U' AND the previous consecutive globalx coordinate of this vehicle was less than reference coordinate at 'U'. This means that if df has 100 vehicles then there will be 100 'yes' in 'u' column because every vehicle will meet the above criteria once. I have tried to do this by running the function with ifelse and also tried to do the same using a for loop but it doesn't work for me. The output should have one new column:

```
vehicle frame globalx class velocity lane u
```

I tried using `ifelse` inside for loop and a function but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized. No need for `for`. `within(df, u <- globalx > your.coord)`

Comment: @mlt there are 2 conditions, globalx at a frame 't' e.g. frame 45 should be greater than reference coordinate u AND at the consecutive previous frame 44 the globalx should be less than reference coordinate as shown in image. How can I specify that R should look into consecutive frames? I tried globalx[i]>6451179.1116 & globalx[i-1] < 6451179.116 but it didn't work.

Comment: Something alike `ref < globalx && (globalx-ref > c(diff(globalx), 0))`. Check on arguments order in `c()`. Note that if you have different vehicle ids, you'd better off doing it with `ddply` from plyr or alike.

Comment: Awesome. Lets give more speeding tickets to people based on mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the data frame is sorted primarily for `vehicle` and secondarily for `globalx`. If it's not you can do it by:

```
idx <- with(df,order(vehicle,globalx))
df <- df[idx,]
```

Now, you can perform it with the following vectorized operations:

```
# example reference line
U <- 6451220
# adding the extra column
samecar <- duplicated(df[,"vehicle"])
passU <- c(FALSE,diff(sign(df[,"globalx"]-U+1e-10))>0)
df[,"u"] <- ifelse(samecar & passU,"yes","no")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

First create dummy data, based on your provided data (I have saved it to `data.txt` on my desktop), duplicate the data so that there are two cars with the same identical data, but different vehicle id's:

```
library(plyr)
df <- read.table("~/Desktop/data.txt",header=T)
df.B <- df; df.B$vehicle = 3 #For demonstration
df <- rbind(df,df.B); rm(df.B)
```

Then we can build a function to process:

```
mvt <- function(xref=NULL,...,data=df){
  if(!is.numeric(xref)) #Input must be numeric
    stop("xref must be numeric",call.=F)
  xref = xref[1]

  ##Split on vehicle and process.
  ddply(data,"vehicle",function(d){
    L = nrow(d) #Number of Rows
    d$u = FALSE #Default to Not crossing

    #One or more rows can be checked.
    if(L == 1)
      d$u = (d$globalx > xref)
    else if(L > 1){
      ix <- which(d$globalx[2:L] > xref & d$globalx[1:(L-1)] <= xref)
      if(length(ix) > 0)
        d$u[ix + 1] = TRUE
    }

    #done
    return(d)
  })
}
```

Which can be used in the following manner:

```
mvt(6451216)
mvt(6451217)
```